# SVG to Android Shape

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics, shapes

I'm wondering how vector drawing in Android with the `Shape` class may resemble another vector drawing standard.

Since `Shape` is a `Drawable`, and Drawables are usually defined as XML, it sounds a lot like the vector drawing commands in SVG.

My question is this: Has anybody created an XSLT transformation, or other mechanism, for converting an SVG drawing description into Android Shapes?

Comment: I am also looking for something like this and am quite puzzled why this is not implemented jet. As you mentioned simple transformation of drawing commands would be enough (at least for a subset of SVG). I have even done this sometimes manually for very simple shapes (defining button backgrounds with gradient like this is great) and I am more or less clueless about SVG specifics.

Comment: Great question, wrong call to close it. I think it is a fantastic idea to have a converter from SVG to Shape. I may write one, but I hate XSLT so I'd probably do it using C# or I guess it should be Java.

Comment: I would suggest you using VectorDrawable. The best solution I found is the BetterVectorDrawable lib together with the SVG to VectorDrawable Converter.

**BetterVectorDrawable** is the VectorDrawable implementation for Android 4.0+ with configurable fall-back behavior on Android 5.0+.

**SVG to VectorDrawable Converter** is the batch converter of SVG images to Android VectorDrawable XML resource files. Online version: http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing that I could find was [svg4mobile](http://code.google.com/p/svg4mobile/).

While I don't believe that it does transformations to Drawables XML, it does read the svg and make the appropriate calls to the Drawable classes.

Answer (score 26):

Another non-GPL'd library (this one is Apache License 2.0), the one used in Google's Androidify app: svg-android

https://github.com/pents90/svg-android

Answer (score 11):

Well, not exactly. But I do have ported libsvg to android, which enables you to load SVG files and plot them to a Canvas.

Please check out:

https://launchpad.net/libsvg-android

Comment: Web site says you have to download using bazaar, simple enough!

Comment: If only it wasn't GPL! Only good for Free software, just so you know

Comment: @AntonP just tryed you lib with an image created with inkscape, around 300kb. That can't render: out of memory error :))

Answer (score 2):

Besides the 2 GPL libraries mentioned, there is a commercial library called [TinyLine](http://www.tinyline.com/) that implements the SVG Tiny subset, which although more limited may be a better licensing choice, if you want to create a non-GPL'd application.

Answer (score 2):

Currently some people including me work on it independently.
You may find working solution in these articles:
  [Android. ImageView with SVG Support.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidImageViewSVG.aspx)
  [Android ImageView and Drawable with SVG support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/Android_SVG_support.aspx)

Comment: tried both can't compile it the ndk part, it would be halpfully if you would update the project settings

Answer (score 2):

The great [AndEngine](http://andengine.org) has an extension for loading SVG and rasterizing it into the texture with any resolution, with color replacement and other great features. Really works. For example you can try [a free game](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.anddev.farmtower.eco) by engine author.

Note: The engine best suited for full-screen 2D games and is based on OpenGL 2 view. LGPL

Comment: "The great AndEngine..." better say "The great buggy AndEngine..."