# how to read svg file

Tags: android

can any one tell me which classes supports to read & display svg files in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

https://launchpad.net/libsvg-android

as found in this other question [SVG to Android Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969037/svg-to-android-shape)

Comment: i have small dbt,is there any possible to read pdf directly without any third party tool in android without converting to svg

Comment: no idea (not an expert), id doesn't seem to be supported natively, there are some apps that do it but I don't know if they are lighter. you could pre convert it to images ? (by preconvert I mean if they are in the phone save them as images, if you dl them from a serveur, have the serveur generate an image first).

Comment: if doing like that there is problem, when we selecting any text it won't.

Comment: true, if you editing the pdf my idea becomes useless ^^ sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidSVG](https://bitbucket.org/paullebeau/androidsvg) is a third party library and provides classes to render SVG files.

You may also set the width and height of the SVG file.

Following is a sample code snippet to read an SVG File :

```
val svg = SVG.getFromResource(resources, R.raw.ic_motorcycle_black_24px)

svg.renderToCanvas(canvas)
```

For full example and working Android application refer
[Kotlin Android Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android-tutorial/) - [Android Draw SVG to Canvas](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-draw-svg-to-canvas-example/)